# getting an array of key values from a mulitidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(
   array(
      'display' => 'hi',
      'title' => 'hi'
   ),
   array(
      'display' => 'hi2',
      'title' => 'hi2'
   )
);
```

What I need is an array containing all of the `display` values.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect for `array_column()`. You can use it like this:

```
$values = array_column($array, "display");
print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => hi [1] => hi2 )
```

For more information about `array_column()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php